# Why is onion forbidden in every fast?

Tags: food, fasting

Almost every vegetarian food is valid in at least one fast. Meaning, if one food is not allowed in a particular fast then the same food will be allowed in some other fast. For example,

- In Hanuman's fast salty food is forbidden But we can eat salt in
  Navratra's fast.
- Normal rice is forbidden in Navratra's fast but we can eat it in
  Hanuman's fast and in some others also.
- And almost everything is eatable in Satya Narayana's fast except
  onion and garlic.

By above examples I came to know that if one God rejects one food then some other God accepts the same food.

Onion (and may be garlic also) is the food which is not allowed in any of the fasts.

- Why do all Gods reject onion?
- Why is onion rejected in every fast?

Comment: onion & garlic incite rajo guna (they are scientifically known as nervous stimulants and aphrodisiac sexual desire due to zinc content). Not just in fast, they are completely shunned even in daily diet for brahmins, and also jains. there is also purana about how these type of items called leeks, grew from cow's meat that was kept aside for personal consumption during sacrifice, which is wrong. Only the remnants of yagna are pure. Same during shraddha, or even feeding guest (athithi) - should not first keep aside food for ourselves.

Comment: @ram But I use to eat onion and sometimes even in salad also. So should I stop eating onion at least in salad?

Comment: Onions are avoided as Onions are not Satvik. Since during fasting we need to concentrate of God always, we should take only Satvik food. Onions are Rajasic. So, we shoud avoid them. Also, this is the reason people suggest to go to temple without taking food.

Comment: @ram Being a Brahmin you have committed immense sin by eating eggs, non veg, onion etc. what will you do now?

Comment: @Rohit. One don't need to worry about his past sins if he has faith in Lord. If he is true devotee of Lord and use to do prayer of him then Lord will make him/her free from every sin. There are lots of effective ways of praying Lord and please him. Like I use to do fasts. I was non-vegetarian long ago. But I left it and now I don't eat non-veg at all. But I am not worried about past meal of mine coz I have faith in my Rama. He will take care of my all sins for me :)

Comment: Great. @Rishabh True. BG too says the same. He eradicates stock of sins.

Comment: According to ayurveda, onion and garlic are rajasic and tamasic which means that they increase passion and ignorance. Rajasic and tamasic foods are detrimental to meditation and devotions. So both are forbidden during fast.

Answer (score 9):

That's because eating onions is forbidden not just during fasts, but at all times.  Here's what [this chapter](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/manu/manu05.htm) of the Manu Smriti says:

> laśunaṃ gṛñjanaṃ caiva palāṇḍuṃ kavakāni ca | 
>   abhakṣyāṇi dvijātīnāmamedhyaprabhavāni ca ||
>
> Garlic, leeks and onions, mushrooms and (all plants), springing from impure (substances), are unfit to be eaten by twice-born men.

EDIT: Here's another verse from the same chapter of the Manu Smriti:

> chatrākaṃ viḍvarāhaṃ ca laśunaṃ grāmakukkuṭam | 
>  
>   palāṇḍuṃ gṛñjanaṃ caiva matyā jagdhvā pated dvijaḥ ||
>
> A twice-born man who knowingly eats mushrooms, a village-pig, garlic, a village-cock, onions, or leeks, will become an outcast.

Prayaschitta for this sin is laid out in chapter 11 of the Manu Smriti.

Comment: Where's the original Sanskrit quote that you have given? I see only English translation in your link. edit. found it here https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc200379.html

Comment: unfit or forbidden? Only unfit. not forbidden?

Comment: Unfit is just the english word, u need to see the sanskrit, abhakshya, which means not to be eaten Or not fit to be eaten. @Rohit.

Comment: This conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64520/discussion-on-answer-by-keshav-srinivasan-why-is-onion-forbidden-in-every-fast).

Answer (score 1):

Onion and garlic contain  sulphone hydroxyl ions which are brain stimulants.

It should be pointed out that garlic and onion are avoided by spiritual adherents because they stimulate the central nervous system, and can disturb vows of celibacy.

Comment: Welcome To hinduism SE! Pls. add some sources  in  support of  your answer.Answers on this site should be backed by sources.

Answer (score 1):

On the contrary.

It is rich in vitamins A- B6- C- E (known as the anti-aging vitamin). Potassium. Iron. Sodium.  Folic acid.

It is known to prevent cholera and plague. It will regulate blood sugars  therefore good for those with diabetes. (Journal of Medecinal Food).

Onions contain quercetine which is very helpful to prevent osteoporoses in women... ( Read the Lancet Health magazine to know more).

Because of it's high content in iron it helps to prevent anemia...

Most religious people will always try to control you.
Onions have been know for centuries to fight flu and prevent lung problems.

Source: World Health Organization.

P.S.  Once again... they will not 'excite' your libido.
I repeat... on the contrary ... ask any 'educated' health doctor (minimum 7 years of university) their zinc content will help you in not contracting prostate cancer. Because of the use of chemical fertilizer in the past 100 years this disease is rampant worldwide. Why? Because vegetables nowadays contain 15 times less zinc ... The sperm count is so low nowadays that our 'humanity' is 
at stake.

P.S. We should learn from history. Greek athletes only ate garlic or onions before the Olympics 2000 years ago.

Comment: Scientific answers are not allowed. You should only answer from Religious or spiritual point of view.

Comment: Sorry... i come from a democratic society. Where there is a lot of education. And our health system known worldwide.  I am answering from a religious point of view. I learned latin for a few years. Religion comes from religare. To unite... therefore my answer is meant to help others. Because 'God' created all things... therefore the truth has to be taught... God would of course allow his children to know about one of the greatest foodsource he gave us: onions and garlic!

Comment: @edmourgagnon - Yes Thanks for your help! .I agree that our healthcare system is not as good as some European or American countries. But here in Hinduism scriptures a very effective healthcare system called Ayurveda is already present from last 2000 years , which addresses the root cause of disease. And yes Brahma is said to be it's author.

Comment: @edmourgagnon-  Billions of Indians as well as westerns are now following Ayurveda and Yoga , which is preventing disease being born in first place. So a answer from Ayurveda point of view will be more appropriate.